# Rstudio Count the values seperately within patterns

Tags: r

I used this:

```
Enquête_Communicatie_Nevobo %>%
  group_by(Team_samenstelling) %>%
  count() %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(per=scales::percent(`n`/sum(`n`))) %>%
  arrange(desc(Team_samenstelling))
```

And this is what came out

```
# A tibble: 28 x 3
   Team_samenstelling                                                                  n per  
   <chr>                                                                           <int> <chr>
 1 met mijn vriendengroep;met mijn sportteam;met mijn familie                          6 1.7% 
 2 met mijn vriendengroep;met mijn sportteam                                          30 8.4% 
 3 met mijn vriendengroep;met mijn familie                                             1 0.3% 
 4 met mijn vriendengroep                                                             58 16.2%
 5 met mijn sportteam;met mijn familie                                                 1 0.3% 
 6 met mijn sportteam                                                                 55 15.4%
 7 met een goede vriend;met mijn vriendengroep;met mijn sportteam;met mijn familie    10 2.8% 
 8 met een goede vriend;met mijn vriendengroep;met mijn sportteam                     22 6.1% 
 9 met een goede vriend;met mijn vriendengroep;met mijn familie                        7 2.0% 
10 met een goede vriend;met mijn vriendengroep                                        21 5.9% 
# ... with 18 more rows
```

I want to make it look this (with the right percentages ofcourse)

```
Team_samenstelling                                                                  n   per
   <chr>                                                                           <int> <dbl>
1 Alleen                                                                            72   
2 met een goede vriend                                                              173  
3 met mijn vriendengroep                                                            188
4 met mijn sportteam                                                                176
5 met mijn familie                                                                  55
```

I have to split the groups before counting them... somehow

Comment: Can you add data using `dput(Enquête_Communicatie_Nevobo)` ? See [here on how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 1):

If you first split the Team_samenstelling string variable into a list of the separate teams (with `str_split`), you can then `unnest` these lists, which will give you each separate Team in its own row. You can then use this new variable to calculate the summary statistics. I think this will get you the result you want:

```
Enquête_Communicatie_Nevobo %>%
  mutate(Team = str_split(Team_samenstelling, ";", simplify = FALSE)) %>%
  unnest(Team) %>%
  group_by(Team) %>%
  count() %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(per=scales::percent(`n`/sum(`n`))) %>%
  arrange(desc(Team))
```